# Need Help with a Powerapps Chart

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, chart

I am new to PowerApps.

I just want to create a pie chart or bar chart in PowerApps that is linked to a SharePoint list column called status that will count the number of times the following records occur.

- Under Review
- Hold
- Submitted
- Not Started
- In Progress/On track
- Will Not Implement
- Complete

I have looked everywhere and I can't make it work.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this....Considering you already have datasource create based on SharePoint List, you can do following.

On any screen, From insert tab, select pie chart.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/use-line-pie-bar-chart

Select pie chart, select Items properties and add below formula

```
AddColumns(GroupBy(AddColumns(CustomList, "NewOfficeField", Status.Value), "NewOfficeField", "StatusColumn"), "CountbyStatus", CountRows(StatusColumn))
```

Here CustomList is your List data source
Status is your column name of type choice. 
It should give you below output.

[image]

Let me know if it worked?

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I followed your directions and still can't get it to work                                                         
                                                                 
 AddColumns(GroupBy(AddColumns(Tracker, "NewOfficeField", Status.Value), "NewOfficeField", "StatusColumn"), "CountbyStatus", CountRows(StatusColumn))

Comment: Is your status column choice ? Are you getting error or chart is not rendering at all without error ?